# Vuetify, set value to v-select ignoring items

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to set a given string to v-select but no idea of how to do this (it is only displayed when I use a a valid :items value), I dropped using v-model because I have an object to store the data, and I'm also constantly adding/deleting items so users cannot choose a given option twice.

Here's the code:

```html
<v-select v-for="(item, index) in securityQuestions" :key="index"
    :menu-props="{ offsetY: true }"
    outlined
    dense
    placeholder="Choose a question"
    :items="optionsComputed"
    :value="item.question" // * <---------------------- this is my goal
    @input="addQuestion(item, index, $event)"
></v-select>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
      options: [
        "Question 1",
        "Question 2",
        "Question 3",
        "Question 4",
        "Question 5"
      ],
      securityQuestions: [
        { question: "", value: "" },
        { question: "", value: "" },
        { question: "", value: "" },
        { question: "", value: "" },
        { question: "", value: "" },
        { question: "", value: "" }
      ]
    }
},
methods: {
    addQuestion(item, index, event) {
      if (item.question !== "") {
        this.options.push(item.question);
      }
      this.options.splice(this.options.indexOf(event), 1);
      this.securityQuestions[index].question = event;
    }
}
```

Any idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use item-value and item-text props of v-select.

This code is working but have a problem, you can't have 2 questions with same answer in value.

```
<template>
  <v-app v-if="securityQuestions && options && answers">
    <v-select
      v-for="(item, index) in securityQuestions"
      :key="index"
      :menu-props="{ offsetY: true }"
      outlined
      dense
      :disabled="answers[index] !== undefined"
      :placeholder="answers[index] || options[index]"
      :items="questions"
      item-text="question"
      item-value="value"
      @input="addQuestion(item, index, $event)"
    ></v-select>
    Your selection: {{ answers }}
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: [
        "Question 1 - Blablabla?",
        "Question 2 - What more?",
        "Question 3 - You did it?",
        "Question 4 - Of couse?",
        "Question 5 - Anything more?",
        "Question 6 - Goal!"
      ],
      securityQuestions: [
        { question: "Option 1", value: "O1", used: false },
        { question: "Option 2", value: "O2", used: false },
        { question: "Option 3", value: "O3", used: false },
        { question: "Option 4", value: "O4", used: false },
        { question: "Option 5", value: "O5", used: false },
        { question: "Option 6", value: "O6", used: false }
      ],
      answers: [],
      optionSelected: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addQuestion(item, index, value) {
      this.answers[index] = value;
      this.securityQuestions[
        this.securityQuestions.findIndex(
          el => el.value === value && el.used === false
        )
      ].used = true;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    questions() {
      return this.securityQuestions.filter(obj => {
        return obj.used === false;
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here you are codesandox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-with-vuetify-eagles-413zf

Comment: tried this already and didn't work. looks like item-text and item value is to display the wanted content when using objects as items.

Comment: @WilliamColmenares Are you using array of string to show it? is not a good use, maybe its better to transform toarray of objects with answer and question.

Comment: tried with object and the same, the problem is, if I delete (or deactivate the item so is not shown anymore in the others dropdowns), is not going to be displayed in the dropdown where was selected. I need a way after selecting an item, put a random string at least replacing the selection... So this way I can place the string stored in the securityQuestions object

Comment: I will think about, probably will have to add watcher and computed property to render but its only an idea, i will think a bit more.

Comment: Probably im not understanding your goal at all. You need to have 6 v-select, each one with their own questions (options? as placeholder for example) and answers (securityQuestions) and when you select one of that v-select need to kick that value and insert another random?. Its a bit confuse, if you can explain a bit more will be easiest to help you. Thanks!

Comment: The behavior wanted is when a user selects an item, do not show that already selected item in the next dropdowns, so what Im doing is a method deleting it from the items array, but as soon as the method deletes the item the text goes away from the v-select.

So I'm looking to replace that text with something not related to the :items array

Not sure if I'm being clear, this is just to avoid headaches during validations later.. thank you.

Comment: Ok, and do you want to insert a new row to keep with X items in every dropdowns?
Example: Dropdown 1 [A,B,C] => Select A, (insert D) Dropdown 2 [B,C,D] => Select C, (insert E)  Dropdown 3 [B,D,E]....

Comment: Not insert, just remove the already selected so cannot be selected again.

Example: 

Dropdown 1: [A,B,C] => Select A,

Dropdown 2: [B,C]

Comment: Updated and working. Selected answer is blocked for security reasons. So maybe you will have to free with a button, but you can use as example for your top goal.

Comment: Tried for several days with different methods trying to add the selected option to the items array so it can appear in the selected but not in the other ones with no luck. It seems this is a known issue and wont be fixed for now:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4000

 For now ill do something like that, however being able to change the opacity of the placeholder would be great.

Comment: Something like this:

.custom-placeholder input::placeholder {
  color: #000 !important;
  opacity: 1;
}

Does the job great.. Thank you so much!

Comment: I was searching but i didnt find how to set ::placeholder, all v-select items have prefix vs__ but it doesnt work. I give you a little of documentation about CSS: https://vue-select.org/guide/css.html.